# How do I login as root user in Lubuntu?

Tags: permissions, fonts, root, lock-screen

I want to login as root not open a root terminal. I am new to linux in general so maybe what I am saying makes no sense. I want to add fonts to the system and change the background of the login screen which on trying I get `Permission Denied` and the solution seems to be getting root access.

---

I am running Lubuntu 21.10 BTW.

Comment: Ubuntu is designed to use `sudo`, not `root`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo to get you on the right track.

Comment: Logging into a GUI using root is **not** a good idea. Yes Xorg allows for it; but the world is tightening security which includes moving to Wayland which does **not** allow root to access the GUI; so even if Xorg desktops like LXQt it's not encouraged (*and not possible using LWQt I believe*).  Seeking root login is not an appropriate answer to whatever your issue is in my opinion.

Comment: So how can I add fonts to my system and change the login background if you happen to know?

Comment: To add fonts - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-install-fonts-in-lubuntu-20-04/1654/2 maybe helpful & to change the background for the greeter (`sddm`) I mention it in this answer https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/change-login-screen-in-lubuntu-21-10/2877/4  (Sorry that post was long & I abandoned where I was going, as whilst I achieved my goal I didn't think suitable for end-users asking.. but search for "*Changing the background sddm wallpaper*" and you'll have the answer you want..

Comment: If you want an answer on this site; you'll need to re-word your question to ask for that detail; though you're welcome to do it yourself (ie. if you follow advice in prior comment & achieve your goal; reword your question then you can write your own answer; you can credit me if you wish if helpful..)

Comment: Yes both my issues have been solved thanks for the help.